# How to configure Bluemail to NOT group emails

Tags: notifications, email

I am using the Bluemail email app and when an email is received on my android phone I get a notification on my phone showing who it is from and the subject.  But if I do not discard the notification, then when I get a second email then the notification says "2 new emails", so I can't see, from my lock screen, the email details for the 2nd and subsequent emails like I can for the first email until I discard the notification.
Are there any settings in Bluemail or Android O/S where I turn off the grouping of emails, so that I can see the details of each email, or if not are there any other email apps where this setting exists?
I have also tried -  Email by Edison, Email TypeApp, K-9 Mail and myMail and these are all no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying 6 different email apps I figured that may be all email apps send a notification of "2 new emails" for the 2nd email unless you clear the first, so I tried a couple of work-a-rounds for my use case which is to be able to view email notifications on my smart watch:

1. I tried using IFTTT where I created a trigger to send a notification when it receives an email.  This sort of worked, but notifications are not replaced, they are added and I couldn't find a way to clear all notifications from IFTTT - specifically when I went into IFTTT it does not clear notifications as it does if you go into email app, so the only way was to clear ALL notifications including other non-email apps.
2. I installed a notification blocker - the one that seemed to work best was [Notification Blocker & Cleaner & Heads-up Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.easy4u.ncleaner) as this does not delete notifications, but puts them in separate folder called junk, so now I always get full notification details of every email on my watch and if I go into Junk folder notification on my phone then I can see history of all email notifications and I can clear them all from here.

So using a notification blocker works really well and solves my issue.